# How does Stack Overflow make it so their apple-touch-icon doesn't have a border effect

Tags: html, favicon

After going through the page source, I found:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69">
```

But even after I did that, my image still has a bored effect. My image is also a transparent png. Any ideas?

[image]

Here is my attempt (10.10.1 OS X Yosemite, Safari: Version 8.0.2):

[image]

I used this website to generate the favico:

http://realfavicongenerator.net

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
```

[image]

Comment: can you show a picture of your icon? What have you tried?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I tried using this image to test it out: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69

Comment: Stack overflow icon is 158x158, your icons are all smaller, I'm not certain but try resizing your icon to 158x158.

Comment: @Martin I resized to 158, nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things in this answer:

- How I did to reproduce StackOverflow's behavior
- Why this may not be a good idea

**How to reproduce StackOverflow's behavior**

What I did:

- Download http:////cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
- Submit this picture to [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) (full disclosure: I'm the author of this site)
- Put the generated pics and HTML in a test web site
- Access it with Safari and add a bookmark

I got your expected result, ie. a transparent background.

[image: Safari bookmark]

This is basically what you did, so there must be something wrong. A few tips:

- There can be a lot of issues with favicon, whatever the browser. They often cache the old icon and do not load the new one. Sometimes they do not load your icon at all, but load it if you wait a few seconds. And so on. My advice: try to use another domain to make sure you start from a fresh state.
- Maybe your test web site as some additional stuff that can conflict with your actual test. For example, if you have a file `apple-touch-icon.png` in your root directory, Safari may load it, even if it is not declared in your HTML code.

**Why this may not be a good idea**

Mac OS Safari relies on the Touch icon, primarily designed for iOS. It is mainly used for the "Add to home screen" feature. In that case, iOS prevents transparency and fills transparent regions with black. Add StackOverflow.com to the home screen and you get:

[image: StackOVerflow to iOS screen]

Honestly the result is okay, but is this really what SO expected? Your choice.

Comment: Thank you for what you posted, I figured out what the problem was... it seems that safari will treat TLD's differently. I cloned my site to a `.com` and it worked. The exact same code. See my answer below.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I add a `www` to my `www.mysite.io` it will work. but without the `www` it won't. It seems like the safari browser doesn't like certain TLD's, and requires them to use `www` to work correctly.

Comment: Hum... I didn't know that. Really unexpected! Thank you for having investigated that and posted an answer to report your results. Devil lies in details!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem here.

The farthest one on the right has a TLD of `.io`

The center one has a TLD of `.com`

They are exact clones, the same code on. So it must be because the domain TLD is not `.com/.net`

[image]

---

**Edit:**
To further recap information I found about this. It seems like adding a `www` in front of my domain, allows it to be fully transparent.

- `mysite.com` works
- `www.mysite.com` works
- `mysite.io` **doesn't** work
- `www.mysite.io` works

Answer (score 1):

Transparent Apple Touch icons are indeed possible. What you need to do is strip all excess information from the PNG using [ImageOptim for Mac](https://imageoptim.com/mac) or a similar program on Windows. I did extensive research and stumbled on the answer by looking at the Apple Touch icon used by the Virtual DJ site. This icon keeps its transparent background on iOS and MacOS Sierra. I looked at the file size and realized how small it was compared to the custom apple touch icons with transparency that I made for my favorites in Safari. Next I looked at the file information using the inspector in Mac's Preview app. All of my custom apple touch icons had four tabs in the inspector section named General, exif, PNG and TIFF. The virtual DJ icon only had two tabs named PNG and General. Once I ran my custom images through ImageOptim the file sizes plummeted by over 90% and the extra TIFF and exif tabs disappeared from the inspector in Preview. Sure enough once I reloaded my custom images and launched Safari all of my Favorites tabs have transparent backgrounds!

[image: Screenshot showing transparent Apple Touch icons]